# Crm 2015 Solution Import Error : Business Unit with id does not exist

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

i am trying to import a solution with all the security roles from dev to another environment. the solution

- is unmanaged solution
- contains only the security roles
- contains all the role from the dev environment including the system admin. although the system admin or any other out of the box crm roles has not been changed.

i am getting the error mentioned in the subject. i've tried importing the custom solutions only. also funny enough no business unit with the specified id can be found in the dev environment.

can any one please help.

Comment: There are no references to Business Unit IDs in the exported XML. Have you made any changes to your target environment that would be relevant for us to know?

Comment: I checked for the reference of the business unit in the customization and came up with the same conclusion as you. we created some business unit but security roles are not assigned to anything yet...